# Subtract months from current date sql

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

I am trying to substract dates from today (Get a 1 month ago till forever report). So far I've tried

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Here is the context:

```
SELECT contracts.currency , ROUND(SUM( 
    CASE
        WHEN contracts.currency = 'USD' THEN contracts.value*550
        WHEN contracts.currency = 'UF' THEN contracts.value*22000
        ELSE contracts.value
    END),2)
    AS real_value
FROM contracts
WHERE currency IN ('USD','UF','CLP') AND date >=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY currency 
ORDER BY currency ASC
```

Comment: Are you looking for a date range that starts on the first day of the month prior to the present one?  What problem are you having with your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps :

```
SELECT contracts.currency , ROUND(SUM( 
CASE contracts.currency
    WHEN 'USD' THEN contracts.value*550
    WHEN 'UF'  THEN contracts.value*22000
    ELSE contracts.value
END),2)
AS real_value
FROM contracts
WHERE currency IN ('USD','UF','CLP') AND 
      date >=DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
      date <=curdate()
GROUP BY currency 
ORDER BY currency ASC
```

If not, it would be nice to check the type of the column "date" in table. Sometimes it is varchar instead of date. This is in case you are not the one who has created the table.

Comment: It is formated as date, aslo I forgot to say that it was from one month ago till forever. Anyways the code until 
date >=DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) didn't work either

Comment: Are you getting an error or are the results not what you expected ? If you can elaborate a little bit. Thanks,

Comment: It says there is a parsing error somewhere missing a right parenthesis, I know it's stupid but I see every parenthesis well balanced and it's basically the same query that I had

Comment: I am certain that date_sub is written correctly. I edited the case statement, you might want to try that once. Thanks